# Using C++ strings with C library functions

Tags: c++, string

The error occurs when I try to use the atoi(const char*) function in the following line...

```
externalEncryptionRawHolder[u] = atoi(parser.next());
```

The 'parser' object is a string parser and the 'next' method returns a string. I think the error has something to do with the fact that the string within the 'atoi' function isn't a constant... but I'm not sure. The gist of the error is 'cannot convert string to const char *'. How can I make my string constant? Any help would be very appreciated (by the way, in case you're wondering what the index 'u' is, this is within a 'for' loop).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to call `c_str()` on the `string` object to get a `const char*`:

```
externalEncryptionRawHolder[u] = atoi(parser.next().c_str());
```

Note, though, that you *should not* do this:

```
const char* c = parser.next().c_str();
```

Because `c` will point to the memory that was managed by the `string` returned by `parser.next()`, which gets destroyed at the end of the expression, so then `c` points to deallocated memory. The first example is ok though because the string is not destroyed until after `atoi` has returned.

Answer (score 1):

`string::c_str()` will convert a `string` to a `const char*`, which is what atoi expects.

```
externalEncryptionRawHolder[u] = atoi(parser.next().c_str());
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll thank you as soon as able (7 minutes). Say, why does that work?

Comment: @Monkeyanator just because `next()` returns a `string` which is incompatible with what the function `atoi` expects, which is a `const char*`. `string` has a member function `c_str()` though, which returns a `const char*` to the string it manages internally, which `atoi` can work with

Comment: @Monkeyanator: Seth is right.  `string` and `char*` can both represent text, but they aren't the exact same thing.  This works because you're converting one form to the other.